# change radar color on condition using existing js file variable

Tags: javascript, html, css, if-statement, background-color

I have a radar_box div which is color #7eb6ff, i want to change the color to red if the jsonstr value in external javascript file is above 100. my code is so far doing nothing:

html:

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../declare.js"></script>

        <section id="alert">
        <h1>alert</h1><br><br>
        <div class="radar_box_area">
            <div class="radar_box" id="radar_box">
                <div class="radar"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script>
            var mmm=document.getElementById("radar_box");
            function cond(){
                if(jsonstr > 100){
                    mmm.style.backgroundColor("red");
            }}

       </script>
    </section>
```

my declare.js file:

```
var jsonstr = ["131.05\r\n"]
```

if the solution is to write my condition in js file, i can't do it because declare.js is created when i run python code. so the whole file is rewritten.

Answer (score 0):

in `cond` function use this snippet.
what we done here is just replace any `spaces`, convert return str to `number` by using `+` sign and then compare with value.

```
var jsonstr = ["131.05\r\n"];
const check = +jsonstr[0].replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm, '')

if (check > 100) {
  console.log('in', check)
}
```